# What's wrong with the IP address here in node.js?

Tags: node.js

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request,response){
    response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello, world!");
    response.end();
}).listen(8888,'127.0.0.2');
```

However, when I run `node test.js` I got

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1020:19)
    at listen (net.js:1061:10)
    at net.js:1143:9
    at dns.js:72:18
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

It works fine with `127.0.0.1` or without specifying the IP addr at all. Can anyone explain why the error happens and how should I correctly specify an address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use that address, you would have to have an interface on your system configured with that address.  Your loopback interface is configured to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: How to configure loopback interface on a mac?

Comment: @Zock77 Post a new question on SuperUser.com.